# I may have 2 versions of Node.js on my server. Do I need to remove one or both or start over?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

This morning I installed `node.js` on `Ubuntu 16.04`.  I am using DigitalOcean.  I used these lines of code and everything went great.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

`sudo apt-get install npm`

I checked the version number and saw that it was an older version.

`nodejs -v // v4.2.6`

Unfortunately that's when I screwed up.  I found a way to upgrade to the latest version on [this page on David Walsh's blog](https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs).

So I typed in the following to upgrade to the latest version of node.

`sudo npm cache clean -f`

`sudo npm install -g n`

`sudo n stable`

I checked the version but it was the same.

`nodejs -v // v4.2.6`

But then I checked node.

`node -v // v9.2.0`

so now I've got a node version and a nodejs version.  Did I hose my server?  How do I fix this trainwreck?  Thanks for any help!  (facepalm)